# I want to copy the workbook from other path to my active workbook, but error is shown when i run below

Tags: vba, excel

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim ABC As Workbook
    Dim XYZ As ThisWorkbook

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Set XYZ = ThisWorkbook
    Set ABC = Workbooks.Open("F:\Test\ABC.csv")

    With ABC
        .Copy After:=XYZ.Sheets(XYZ.Sheets.Count)
        .Close False
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: please add the error that's being returned

Comment: Is `Dim XYZ As ThisWorkbook` a valid declaration? I've not seen that before.  Maybe `Dim XYZ As Workbook` would work?

Answer (score 0):

> With ABC
>      .Copy After:=XYZ.Sheets(XYZ.Sheets.Count)
>       .Close False End With

In the above line ABC is a workbook where is the sheet reference of the ABC workbook?

Use sheet reference too.

```
With ABC.Sheets("MySheet")
```

Or

```
With ABC.Sheets(1)
```